# Group content by taxonomy term, but then also list all terms in each row

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm looking for help with creating a view.

I have a content type, Thing. Thing has a field on it where you can select multiple terms in a taxonomy, Category. I want my view to look like this:

**Category 1**

- Thing 1

  - Category 1
  - Category 2
- Thing 2

  - Category 1
  - Category 3

**Category 2**

- Thing 1

  - Category 1
  - Category 2

So basically, I want to group by the terms and then list out all terms underneath each Thing. I also don't want groups to end up with headers of "Category 1, Category 2," and I want to make sure each of the terms is listed under each instance of the Thing in the view.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Instead of just adding Category as a single field in the View and trying to figure out how to configure that to show each Category for a Thing row but only one Category header per group, I have the Category field on there twice - one that does not display multiple in one row (for the headers), and one that does display them all within one row (to list out all Categories for a Thing).

I hope this possibly helps someone else!